# Border radius Issue in Previous versions of IE

Tags: css

Rounded corners (border radius) are not displaying in IE8 and previous versions. Is it possible to apply border radius any way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Mmmmm, pie.](http://css3pie.com/)

Comment: Yes, it is possible using the `behavior` property. Sample code available [here](http://starikovs.com/2010/08/24/css3-rounded-corners/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [border-radius.htc](http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser) or [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/).

**Border-radius.htc**

```
.curved {
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  behavior:url(border-radius.htc); /* important line */
}
```

**PIE**

```
.curved {
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  behavior: url(PIE.htc); /* important line */
}
```

Comment: `-moz-border-radius` and `-webkit-border-radius` haven't been used in a very long time...

Answer (score 0):

You could try [CSS Pie](http://css3pie.com/).

Overall, though: I'd let it go. The absence of rounded corners won't break the experience for users in IE8. More capable browsers get the better experience. Progressive enhancement is a beautiful thing.

Comment: I agree with you there. In fact, "a richer viewing experience" with side-by-side screenshots should be a great motivation for people to upgrade. If we waste all our time making sure our sites look beautiful in IE7... why should people upgrade? And if people don't upgrade, we'll always be plagued with obsolete browsers...

Comment: @Kolink Don't forget. IE8 isn't *that* bad. (Not IE7-bad) If I'm not mistaken, XP users can't upgrade further than IE8.

Comment: @BramVanroy True, which is why I at least try to make sure my JavaScript works in IE8 (`querySelectorAll(".class")` instead of `getElementsByClassName("class")`) but still... XP is no longer supported, if I remember correctly.